# Using getElementsByClassName in VBA

Tags: vba

Imagine the following HTML:

```
<div class="TheChef">
    <div class="ChefRestaurant">
        <a class="ChefLink" href="#">Expensive Restaurant</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ChefName">
        <a class="ChefLink" href="#">Gordon Ramsey</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code below, i'm using getElementsByClassName in VBA to get innerHTML from elements:

```
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.example.net", False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

For Each oElement In oHtml.getElementsByClassName("RestaurantTown")
    strTown = oElement.innerHTML
Next oElement
```

However, I need to get the ChefLink from both ChefRestaurant & ChefName elements.

I wondered about oHtml.getElementsByClassName("ChefName").getElementsByClassName("ChefLink") but this doesn't work.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName` method returns a collection of nodes, you should select the node from collection by index, then call the method again:

`oHtml.getElementsByClassName("ChefName")(0).getElementsByClassName("ChefLink")(0)`

Comment: i believe you need to replace "RestaurantTown" with "TheChef".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ChefLink")
```

gives you `[<a class=​"ChefLink" href=​"#">​Expensive Restaurant​</a>​, <a class=​"ChefLink" href=​"#">​Gordon Ramsey​</a>​]`

While `document.getElementsByClassName("ChefLink")[1]` gives you only the second element `<a class=​"ChefLink" href=​"#">​Gordon Ramsey​</a>`

I hope this helps